# How do I fix this routing issue in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added a controller with scaffolding the codes are generated successfully.
But When I move from Index View to Details/Edit/Delete View it says "The resource cannot be found."

Then i checked the URL ,it is like `"http://localhost:57426/Profitcenter/Details/0022%20"`
but the actual URL should like below

```
http://localhost:57426/Profitcenter/Details/0022"
```

How do i fix this issue? and what's the problem with auto generated codes?

Comment: The `%20` represents a space. How are generating the url, and what is the value you passing to the method parameter

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PROFITCENTER_CODE }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PROFITCENTER_CODE }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PROFITCENTER_CODE })

I didn't create anything manually, these are autogenerated code only,
The ID is a string value ,which im passing as a parameter

Comment: No doubt, your PROFITCENTER_CODE value ends in a space, which is why the URL is being built this way.

Comment: Best guess is that your values are stored in the database as a fixed length string. You can always use `.Trim()` to remove whitespace.

Comment: Thank you ,I just added <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" /> in webconfig file ,now it is okay.

Comment: That's not the best idea there King Fisher. You should try the ideas of the ones in the comments first as it is very likely the issue is custom code related.

Comment: @hbulens Sure I will . thank you :)